# UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter for UiWebView

Tags: swift, uiwebview, uiprintformatter

I'm searching how to print the current page in the UiWebView .
I got this :

```
let formatter = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: SearchBar.text)
```

I don't find what I need to write instead of the SearchBar.text for printing the Web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter` you can get a `UIViewPrintFormatter` right from the web view itself:

```
let formatter = myWebView.viewPrintFormatter()
```

[More here on NSHipster.](http://nshipster.com/uiprintinteractioncontroller/)